# Why doesn't functions doesn't return false in python

Tags: python, return, boolean-operations

```
def sleep_in(weekday, vacation):
    if weekday == ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'] and vacation == 'Yes':
        return True
    elif weekday != ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'] or vacation == 'Yes':
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(sleep_in('monday', 'No'))
```

Comment: `weekday` is given as a string, so `weekday != <some list>` will always be True. Did you mean to write `weekday not in <some list>`?

Comment: Note: your first two conditions could be replaced by a single one: `if vacation == "Yes" or weekday not in list_of_weekdays`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some better code:

```py
def sleep_in(weekday, vacation):
    if vacation:
        return True
    if weekday in ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday']:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

This code works because it first checks `vacation`, and returns `True` when vacation is true (you can simply do `if vacation` for this).

Next, if vacation is false, it evaluates the next `if` statement, and sees whether the weekday parameter is within the list of `['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday']`. If it is, it returns False (no sleep_in). If it is not, it means it's a weekend and sleep_in returns true.

I think that's the goal you were trying to achieve.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your pythonic adventures!